# Hazelcast: how to ensure cluster startup is finished

Tags: java, locking, startup, hazelcast

I have a cluster with 3 nodes (in different machines) and I have a "business logic" that use a **distributed lock** at startup.

Sometimes when there is more latency **every** **node** acquires the **exclusive** **lock** **with** **success** because the cluster isn't already "startup" so each node does not yet see the other.

Subsequently the nodes see each other and the cluster is correctly configured with 3 nodes. I know there is a "MemberShipListener" to capture the event "Member added" so I could execute again the "business logic", but I would to know if there is a method to ensure when the cluster startup is properly finished in order to wait to execute the "business logic" until the cluster is on.

I tried to use `hazelcast.initial.wait.seconds` but configure the right seconds isn't deterministic and I don't know if this also delay the member join operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afaik, there is no such thing in Hazelcast. As the cluster is dynamic, a node can go and leave at any time, so the cluster is never "complete" or not.

You can, however :

1. Configure an initial wait, like you described, in order to help with initial latencies
2. use `hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size` to define the minimum number of members hazelcast is waiting for at start
3. Define a minimal quorum : the minimal number of nodes for the cluster to be considered as useable/healthy (see [cluster quorum](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html/clusterquorum.html))
4. Use the `PartitionService` to check is the cluster is safe, or if there are pending migrations